# Ember production build error 'WARN: Output exceeds 32000 characters'

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm, ember-cli, uglifyjs

I'm developing an Ember application,

in that application-

Building application for production environment gives following warning during build process.

On Executing `ember build --environment=production` command

I'm  getting following  warning:

**`WARN: Output exceeds 32000 characters`**

we need to suppress or eliminate this warning.

Answer (score 3):

You need to mention it in `options` object for minifyjs configurations,

```
var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    minifyJS: {
      enabled: true, //by default its enabled for production
      options: {
        "max-line-len": 50000, //you can mention custom value
      }
    }    
  });
```

Comment: This answer is helpful, just a note place the max-line-len in double quotes or build fails with unexpected token -

Comment: I just don't understand why this is worth warning about. We have a pretty small website and yet we're getting the same warning.

Answer (score 3):

Kumkanillam's answer didn't work for me (Ember CLI 2.12.2 with UglifyJS 2.8.22). It was on the right track, though. After some digging I came up with this:

```
var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  minifyJS: {
    enabled: true,
    options: {
      output: { max_line_len: 50000 },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The warning is being generated because of uglify. If you note its [Beautifier options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js#beautifier-options) the `max-line-len` defaults to 32000. Now that is just a warning so no issues there, but if you want to remove that you can set the value of option in ember build.

Comment: i tried the values -b (and) --b (and) max-line-len (and) -max-line-len (and) --max-line-len  with 'ember build --environment=production' but all gives errors. can you tell me how to set this value.

Comment: Getting "The option '--max-line-len' is not registered with the build command

Comment: Maybe set the option in your [`ember-cli-build.js`](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#minifying)